# Google Analytics doesn't show even real time data

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is there a delay between when you open a Google Analytics account and when it starts reporting?

For some reason, my Google Analytics doesn't report anything even though in the browser console everything seems fine.

Did anyone experience a similar issue?

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m) {i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)  [0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-61199413-1', 'none');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Please see that everything looks fine in the browser console.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sometimes there are issues with Real-Time. But generally, if there's nothing wrong, then as soon as you have the tracking code on your site, then it should start collecting data right away, and you would see this in RT reports. You can also install GA Debugger to see if there are any other issues.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I didn't know about GA debugger, but now I installed it, and it shows that everything is good. Nevertheless I'm still not seeing any indication of that my events are logged neither in the real time data nor in the report. I have no idea why it doesn't work...

Comment: It looks like the tracking ID from your snippet above is different from the one shown in the debugger tool (one ending in 413-1, and the other ending in 738-2). Can you check that?

Comment: Thanks for noticing that. In desperation, I tried to create a second account with a second id. This is a screenshot from when I created my second account. Hyun, do you happen to know if domains tend to create problems? Let's say I got the right id code, but wrong domain, and cookie setting is 'none', would it still log at least something? Thank you...

Comment: It sort of started working now... I'm still not sure why it hadn't worked before.

Comment: If you are testing on localhost, then your cookie domain should be set to "none".